# Javascript: If Chrome add padding to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created the code below to detect if Chrome add padding: 28% if all other browsers add margin: 28%.  It's not working as expected and Im curious where I went wrong?

```js
var chromeFix = document.getElementById('#slide-container');

if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
 chromeFix.style.padding += 28%;
} else {
 chromeFix.style.margin += 28%;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad solution...

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Have you tried using the webkit-css-styles?

Comment: I guess you'll have to do some maths to correct your testing code

Comment: Browser sniffing is always a bad idea. Try changing var chromeFix = document.getElementById('#slide-container'); to var chromeFix = document.getElementById('slide-container'); - no # in id name

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to this messy hack, I would suggest looking into a css reset.  Each browser has it's own user agent’ stylesheet, a css reset is designed to clear these styles for cross browser consistency

From http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

**What Is A CSS Reset?**

A CSS Reset (or “Reset CSS”) is a short, often compressed (minified) set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.

**Why Use A CSS Reset?**

You might wonder what this is all for – well, it’s simple. From the consistent base that you’ve set up via your reset, you can then go on to re-style your document, safe in the knowledge that the browsers’ differences in their default rendering of HTML can’t touch you!

Normalize.css is a commonly used css reset

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Just make sure this is the first css reference in your page as it is designed to override, and it will!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution I found....

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    $('#slide-container').css('padding-top', '28%');
    } else {
    $('#slide-container').css('margin-top', '28%');
}
```

Anyone know the proper syntax/way to write the above in pure JS?

Comment: `document.getElementById('slide-container').style.paddingTop = '28%'`